# Error with typescript jest - Property 'any' does not exist on type

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to run a jest test, but I'm getting a type checking error.

Here is a simple test:

```js
describe("testFunc", () => {
  it("shouldn't have a type error", async () => {
    const s = "my string";
    const expected = expect.any(String);
    expect(s).toEqual(expected);
  });
});
```

The `any()` on each expect statement is erroring as:

```
Property 'any' does not exist on type '{ <T extends Func>(spy: T | Spy<T>): FunctionMatchers<T>; <T>(actual: ArrayLike<T>): ArrayLikeMatchers<T>; <T>(actual: T): Matchers<...>; (): NothingMatcher; }'.
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/recommended",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "composite": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "exclude": ["**/dist/*"]
}
```

When I add `import @types/jest` to the top of the file, VSCode does not show any type checking errors. However, when I run the test, I get the following error:

```
error TS6137: Cannot import type declaration files. Consider importing 'jest' instead of '@types/jest'.
```

Importing `'jest'` causes `any()` to throw a type checking error. Running the test suite despite VSCode errors still throws the same errors.

Comment: `import @types/anything` is always a bug

Comment: `npm install -D jest @types/jest` then add `import "jest";` to the top of any test entry point modules. Also seriously consider setting `"skipLibCheck": false` in your tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

The entire project also includes an Angular workspace that imports `karma` and `jasmine`. The `expect` used in the test files was auto importing from `jasmine` - this was causing the error.

I was able to get around this by explicitly importing the jest types:

```js
import { describe, it, expect } from "@jest/globals";
```